# Filesystem not showing correct size in Mac OSX

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, dd

I installed a new HDD and transferred my old data to it by using `dd` on my old HDD and then `dd` again to the new HDD. However, when booting from the new HDD, it does not recognize the new, larger disk space, and still thinks it has the old size.

My old HDD was 160 GB and it was near capacity, new HDD is 1TB.

The command I ran to write to my new harddrive was

```
>: sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=/dev/rdisk0s2 bs=131072

>: df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   149Gi  146Gi  2.4Gi    99%    /

>: diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.9 GB   disk0s2
```

How should I fix this? I can run another round of `dd` again if need be.

Comment: Please include the actual commands you ran. Also, what makes you think it does not recognize it? Who doesn't? Could you show us the output of `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information, it is hard to read and harder to format correctly in the comments. Plus, comments can be deleted without warning.

Comment: My `fdisk` does not have `-l` option, so I used `diskutil`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "Disk Utility.app" to resize the main partition on your new HDD.

Comment: Disk Utility only shows one partition on my drive, taking up the entire 1 TB. Disk Utility also shows "Capacity: 1TB, Available: 2GB, Used 150GB."